# Looking for usable immutable bool array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, immutability, immutable-collections

I have a class which has an bool array member. If I modify an element of this array, a new modified copy of the instance should be created. Sounds like a perfect opportunity for using an Immutable type. Googling around showed that Microsoft provides a new library [Immutable Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn769092%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) which works quite well for another use case. But not for the aforementioned bool array member.

The seemingly fitting type ImmutableArray has been removed for time being and the documentation didn't seem to contain an indexer as well. The potential replacement ImmutableList doesn't work with structs. I'm loathe to introduce another third party library, so I'm wondering what options I have and which I should choose.

I could create a class Bool to satisfy the reference type requirement. Or I could use BitArray, but trying to use like this fails with a compile error:

```
IReadOnlyList<BitArray> test = new IReadOnlyList<BitArray>(new BitArray());
```

So any ideas what I should do?

Comment: *ImmutableList* From when? I can use it with a struct.

Comment: @xanatos I tested using ImmutableList with a struct again on a different computer and now it seems to work. Not sure why the problem came up, as I installed the package only two days prior my asking. Nonetheless thanks for testing it yourself, this saves me some trouble. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this is perfectly valid:

```
var ba = new BitArray(10);
ba.SetAll(true);

IImmutableList<bool> test = ba.Cast<bool>().ToImmutableList();
```

Your problem is that the immutable item type is `bool`, not `BitArray`! And that `BitArray` is from the pre-generics era, so it doesn't support `IEnumerable<bool>`, `ICollection<bool>`, `IList<bool>`, so you can't use it directly (see the `.Cast<bool>()` to solve this)

Comment: As mentioned in the comments below my question, it seems to be some kind of installation problem, not an actual problem with bool being a struct and not a reference. I'll still mark it as wanted answer as it does indicate that my original approach should have worked out of the box.